# Splitting columns and getting result as a JsonArray in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, json, timescaledb

I have a table like this:

```
Time  | id/type  | value

1        A/a       10
2        A/b       15
3        A/c       8
4        A/b       2
```

I need to get a Json Array in the format:

`[[Time, value for a, value for b, value for c]]`

For example: for this table

`[[1,10,Null,Null], [2,Null,15,Null],[3,Null,Null,8],[4,Null,15,Null]]`

Could you please help me on this problem? I am quite new to Sql in general, so any help is appreciated.

I have made some attempts as follows:

First convert it into a new_table with layout:

```
Time  | id  | a  | b  | c

1      A   10    Null   Null 
2      A   Null  15     Null
3      A   Null  Null    8
4      A   Null  2      Null
```

and then use

```
with new_table as (
select "Time", split_part("id/type", '/', 1) id,
  case when split_part("id/type", '/', 2) = 'a' then "value" end a,
  case when split_part("id/type", '/', 2) = 'b' then "value" end b,
  case when split_part("id/type", '/', 2) = 'c' then "value" end c
from tablename)
select array_to_json(array_agg(Array[new_table."Time",new_table.a,new_table.b,new_table.c])) from new_table;
```

Using this code in new_table gives the result I expected, but I am not sure if it is the right approach to create a new table every time we need such JsonArray.

Thank you!!

Comment: Do you really have delimited values like `A/a` in a single column?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thank you for your comment. Yes, there is always this delimited value.

Comment: And you always want the character after the delimiter in the output?

Comment: Actually, I just want to get the JsonArray. I have string like location2/nominalvalues in my real table.